# Is there a way in react to redirect a user from one page to the bottom of another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, window.location

I need a redirect from one page in react to the bottom of another page when a user touches a button.

```
const goCart = () => {
   if(window.location.pathname !== '/products'){
     window.location.assign(ProductsPageLink());
     window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
   }
   else{
     window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
   }  
}


<div onClick={goCart} className={classes.shoppingCart} style={{display: isOpen ? 'none' : '',}}>
    ...
</div>
```

The place that would like to be redirected on the second page has an identifier

```
<div id="Cart-redirect-marker"></div>
```

I can't find a way to do the window.location action first and then window.scrollTo later. With the code that I currently have, the opposite occurs, it scrolls on the first page and later redirects to the top of the second.

An idea other than this one that achieves the same goal would still be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with anchors to solve your problem. You just give the element where you want to scroll to an id. For example:

```
<div id="bottom" />
```

Now you can reference it inside of your url: https://example.com/products#bottom
If you change window.location to that url on button click, the window will display the part of your html element.

Comment: I have an identifier id `<div id="Cart-redirect-marker"></div>`, but putting a url type .../products#Cart-redirect-marker It does not redirect me to anything in my react app, it simply updates the page where I am

Comment: Ah wait I forgot, that react uses the # in urls for a different purpose. But there is a package that solves this. You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link